# How to generate valid java code in java program?

Tags: java, templates, export, abstract-syntax-tree

In my application I want to **generate a java source file**. The purpose is to experiment with genetic programming for problem domains that require java compatibility on source level.

Example: I have an in-memory data structure that represents the latest generation of a possibly long running genetic algorithm's solution to a problem. I run .toJavaSource() on my object to get the text that I then save to file and run through javac to test it. The score calculated from the test will be fed back into the genetic algorithm for next iteration.

The naive approaches I could think of would be to make a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) or use a template engine like [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.incubator.apache.org/) or [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/index.html), but this does not guarantee validity of the generated code since none of these approaches know what is valid java syntax.

Is there some existing library that will allow me to work on my java code in the form of an abstract syntax tree or similar DOM model that supports saving to a guaranteed syntax valid source text compatible with oracle javac?

Comment: You might consider a Groovy-based approach instead. I'm not sure exactly how I'd go about this in any case, but Groovy makes it "easy" to interact with the AST directly during compilation, and generating new code in the form of nodes that you attach to the tree is about as simple as code generation is going to get.